# How does this function work without passing any parameters?

Tags: c++, function, oop

Given the below code sample, how do the functions here work without passing any parameters into them?

NOTE: This sample is working as expected

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Cuzmo
{
    private:
        int array[10] = { 95, 45, 48, 98, 485, 65, 54, 478, 1, 2325 };
        int n;

    public:

        Cuzmo ()
        {
            array[10];
            n = sizeof (array) / sizeof (array[0]);
        }

        void printArray ()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                cout << array[i] << endl;
        }

    void bubbleSort ()
    {
        bool swapped = true;
        int j = 0;
        int temp;

        while (swapped)
        {
            swapped = false;
            j++;
            for (int i = 0; i < n - j; ++i)
            {
                if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
                {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Cuzmo sort;

    cout << "Before Bubble Sort :" << endl;
    sort.printArray ();
    cout << endl;

    sort.bubbleSort ();

    cout << "After Bubble Sort :" << endl;
    sort.printArray ();
    cout << endl;

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: This works because C++ allows it. None of the functions require parameters, so you don't have to pass any.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Read the chapter about classes in your C++ book

Comment: Is this already UB `array[10];`? The value is not stored but the array is accessed out of bounds.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes it is.

Comment: That's at least the third time I've seen this code on stackoverflow. Maybe you should form a study group?

Answer (score 0):

passing an argument is not a necessary thing. It totally depends upon the function definition. If in the function definition, you are mentioning that, the function will take some parameters, then passing those parameters during the function call is a must. Else it's totally fine. We can call a function without passing any parameters.